# Excel VBA - Fill ActiveX Combobox with dynamic range from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, combobox

I am trying to fill an ActiveX Combobox with a dynamic range from another workbook but I am getting a run-time error '1004' Application or object-defined error on the line of code that assigns the range:

```
Dim prfile1 As String
Dim prfile2 As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim checktotal As Integer
Dim checkrng As Range
Dim emunber As String

prfile1 = Worksheets("setup").Range("B10").Value
prfile2 = Worksheets("setup").Range("B7").Value
filepath = Worksheets("setup").Range("e10").Value
emunber = Worksheets("ReprintOld").Range("V3").Value

Workbooks.Open filepath & prfile2
Windows(prfile2).Activate

checktotal = Workbooks(prfile2).Worksheets(emunber).Range("AE1")
checkrng = Workbooks(prfile2).Worksheets(emunber).Range(Range("U5"), Range("U5").End(xlDown))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *qualify* all your `Range` objects.

```
checktotal = Workbooks(prfile2).Worksheets(emunber).Range("AE1")

With Workbooks(prfile2).Worksheets(emunber)

    Set checkrng = .Range(.Range("U5"), .Range("U5").End(xlDown))

end with
```

Comment: this now gives me a different error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Hmm. Is the workbook prfile2 open? Is `prfile2` a variable, or the workbook name? If it's the workbook name, it needs to be inside of double quotes, as well as `emunber`. So, `With Workbooks("prfile2").Worksheets("emunber")`. Adding `Option Explicit` to the top of the module would prevent this as well.

Comment: the workbook is open and yes those are variables for the workbook and worksheet.  there is no error for the checktotal line just before this line

Comment: Okay, then is the variable `emunber` of the datatype **String** or datatype **Worksheet**? What does the line look like when you assign `emunber`'s value/object?

Comment: emunber is a String `emunber = Worksheets("ReprintOld").Range("V3").Value`.  This is a value that changes based on a selection in a listbox and `prfile2` contains worksheets that are named after these "V3" values

Comment: I've tested mock data of this and it's working as intended. I can't imagine what the issue would be. Right above the With statement, type `stop`. When it reaches this line, press `Ctrl + G` in the VBE. In the immediate window that pops up, type `? Workbooks(prfile2).Worksheets(emunber) is nothing` and see what it outputs

Comment: it output `False`

Comment: Oh. Thanks for adding your full code. `checkrng` is type `Range`. You will need to use the `Set` keyword for an object. I'll update code

Comment: that got rid of the error! but unfortunately my combobox didn't populate as I had hoped with the code following that `with` statement.  Is there a way to confirm the range that is returned for the `checkrng` variable?

Comment: you can confirm the range by prompting a msgbox (or immediate window again). `MsgBox checkrng.Address` will return something like `$U$5:$U$10` or something along those lines.